# Split Data Frame R

Tags: r

I'm clearly going about this incorrectly, so looking for some advice (newbie R programmer here...) Need to split up a data frame of the AFINN word list into two new vectors (one for positive words and one for negative words). I used subset, but have a few lines here. What's a better way to combine these lines into one line?

```
# read the "AFINN" dataset and assign it into a variable called "AFINN"
AFINN <- read.delim("AFINN.txt", header=FALSE)
AFINN
# change column names to "Word" and "Score"
colnames(AFINN) <- c("Word","Score")
#split the AFINN data frame up into positive and negative word vectors
posAFINN <- subset(AFINN, Score >= 0)
posAFINN <- posAFINN[,-2]
posAFINN

negAFINN <- subset(AFINN, Score <= 0)
negAFINN <- negAFINN[,-2]
negAFINN
```

Comment: Can it be `>=` and just `<`? If so `split(AFINN$Word, AFINN$Score >= 0)` will do it. Or `lapply(split(AFINN, AFINN$Score >= 0), '[', -2, drop = FALSE)`

Comment: `split(AFINN$Word, sign(AFINN$Score))` is an alternative putting zero in a third vector.

Answer (score 1):

Base R:

```
posAFINN <- AFINN$Word[AFINN$Score > 0]
negAFINN <- AFINN$Word[AFINN$Score < 0]
```

Dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
posAFINN <- AFINN %>%
    filter(Score > 0) %>%
    pull(Word)

negAFINN <- AFINN %>%
    filter(Score < 0) %>%
    pull(Word)
```